# $x\in\mathcal{O}_K$ can be written as product of irreducible elements

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, divisibility

> *Lemma:* Every element $x\neq 0$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ with ($K$ an arbitrary number field) can be written as a product of irreducible elements.
>
> *Proof:* We prove this lemma by complete induction on the norm of $x$. For $N(x) = \pm 1$ we have that $x$ is a unit. Let $|N(x)| \geq 2$ and $x$ not irreducible. Then we can write $x$ as $x = yz$ with $y, z$ not units, that means $|N(y)|, |N(z)|\geq 2$. Thus $|N(x)| > |N(y)|, |N(z)|$ and by the induction hypothesis we can write $y$ and $z$ — and consequently also $x$ — as a product of irreducible elements.

- So this lemma means that I'm guaranteed to come to an end with splitting up  $x \in \mathcal{O}_K$ into products of non-units?
- I don't understand the proof. Why shouldn't $y$ and $z$ be irreducible?

Comment: $y$ and $z$ need not be irreducible, but are of strictly lesser norm (i.e. $|N(x)|>|N(y)|, |N(z)|$; the strictness is implied by the fact that $|N(y)|, |N(z)|\geq 2$ and that the norm is multiplicative). Thus, by induction hypothesis, one can write both of them as a product of some irreducibles. Putting these together, one obtains an expression of $x$ itself as a product of irreducibles.

Comment: The condition “irreducible” is not necessary but the philosophy of the theorem is to expose in $O_K$ something analogue to the unique factorization theorem of natural numbers (note that it would not be “relevant” with composite numbers). The ring $O_K$ has a very “strong” structure: is a Dedekind ring (in which irreducible elements are important in connection with maximal ideals). However it is not in general of unique factorization alike with natural numbers.